# A maths paper I wrote a not so long ago about generating an nth terms for an arbitrary collection of numbers. Any corrections and advice appreciated

Tags: sequences-and-series

This link is to the work I am talking about and hopefully it should work. https://1drv.ms/b/s!AvdKrr_1baGk_TbrpPFjmht4D0ol?e=59lZsa

This is the link to the pdf. To put it into some context: I am a 16 year old mathematics student who is passionate about the subject. I initially started thinking about this idea 2 years ago when I solved a puzzles fun it gave me two nth terms- one for odd numbers and one for even numbers. That personally annoyed me because I couldn't write it in one line so I set out to see how I can resolve this and I came up with a solution with simply sines and cosines. However, this year, I came across the same issue again but now that I am older and wiser, I attempted to generalise this idea but looking at periodic functions and other things (the whole aim of this is to not use a Kronecker-delta). By the end of it, I believe I came up with an equation that can define the nth term for a sequence from an arbitrary collection of numbers. Any corrections and advice is wanted. Thanks in advance.

I believe that this trick is a fun thing that people might find interesting in this community

-Karrar

Comment: We shouldn't close this question before giving an advice of what to do with this embryonic research by a talented youth.

Comment: 1) A detail: a certain number of expression (formulas (15), (16)...) having a $\sin(...)$ should contain a $\pi$ inside the parentheses. 2) Besides, are you aware of the fact that the general term of a linear recurrence, for example a second order linear recurrence $u_{n+1}=au_n+bu_{n−1}$ can be expressed as a combination of powers of roots of "characteristic polynomial" here $u_n=p(r_1)^n+q(r_2)^n$ where the characteristic polynomial is $x^2=ax+b$ (when these roots are distinct) ? 3) Complex numbers could be useful in your study

Comment: @Karrar did you try to code this?

Comment: @Jean Marie Thanks for the advice. I can't believe I missed the $pi$ , thanks. I am not aware of the fact that the general term of a linear recurrence, I will have a research and try to understand what you are referring to, iterative sequence but I am not sure if that's what you are referring to. I am not too sure how complex numbers are useful, mind clarifying?

Comment: @Snoop unfortunately I don't know how to code but my intention is to at some point.

Comment: For linear recurrences, see for example [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~arash/55/8_2.pdf)

Comment: @Jean Marie concerning the point about me forgetting to add the pi, I don't think it is actually necessary. It works either way as the terms simply cancel out and the only terms that has an affect is when it is zero. I still added them since you are wiser than me and there is perhaps a more important reason relating to convention. Thank you very much.